# vertical menu three level using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, treeview

I had created a menu by using html coding and jquery such as

```
<ul>
    <li>
        level 2
        <ul>
            <li>level 2.1
            <ul>
                <li>a1
                 <li>a2
                    </ul></li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        level 3
        <ul>
            <li>
                level 4
                <ul>
                    <li>c</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>e</li>
            <li>f</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

​The above is html coding and jquery for this is below:

```
$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();              
});​
```

and I got output such as when i click level 2 it is expanded but when i  expand level 3 level 2 should also collapsed and if in level 2 if  level 2.1 is expanded then it should be expanded.please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).children('ul').show();
      $(this).prev().children('ul').hide();
      $(this).siblings().children('ul li ul').hide();
      $(this).next().children('ul').hide();
  }); 
  $('li > ul').hide();
});
```

Checkout the bin: http://jsbin.com/ebapay/1/edit

Comment: my problem is solved by editing in your code .But now i am facing different problem

Answer (score 4):

#### Propagation works only when you add closing tags.

Look at this part:

```
<li>level 2.1
<ul>
    <li>a1
     <li>a2
        </ul></li>
```

There are no closing `</li>` tags.

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ibiceh/1

---

#### Initial Collapse

Add `$('li > ul').hide();` in the `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(ev) {
        $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
        ev.stopPropagation();              
    });
    $('li > ul').hide();
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ibiceh/2/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i need that suppose if level 2 is already expanded then it should be collapsed as i expand level 3

Comment: That's what is happening... Just open the fiddle, and you will see that all the levels are expanded by default and when you click on the parent, it gets slided up and again, it gets slided down.

Comment: No this is not needed. Initially both should be collapsed.then if i expand level 2 then it will expand then if i click on level 3 then level 2 should have to collapsed automatically & level 3 should be expand

Comment: You can do this way. In the document ready itself, `$('li > ul').hide();` And the fiddle is: http://jsbin.com/ibiceh/2

Comment: No Sir it is not working i need that at a time only one node should be expanded and all other should be collapsed

Comment: Sir i had done some changes in your code: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(ev) {
    $('li > ul').hide();
      $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
      ev.stopPropagation();              
  });
  $('li > ul').hide();
}); but it also does not work properly

Comment: Yeah, I will try to make the change and when works, will post it.

Comment: @user1926384 You cannot do that way in multilevel lists. Just tried that!

Comment: So how can i do this because i need this scenario

Answer (score -1):

my problem is solved by editing the previous given code.But now i am facing a different problem.
As my Html Code is:

```
   <body>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Academic Programme</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Under Graduate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Post Graduate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ph. D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">People</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Director</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Faculty</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Computer Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Information Technology</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mechanical Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Automobile Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Electrical Engineering</a></li>

                            </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Technical Staff</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Administrator Staff</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Supporting Staff</a>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                    <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Computer Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Information Technology</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Electronics & Communication Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Civil Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mechanical Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Automobile Engineering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Electrical Engineering</a></li>

                    </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Amenities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library

            <li><a href="#">Admission</a>
                    <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">UTU</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">GTU</a></li>

                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Student Corner</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Circular</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News&Events</a></li>



         </ul>
```

And my jquery is:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
                $('li').click(function(ev) {
                 ev.stopPropagation();
           $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
         $(this).prev().children('ul').children('li').children('ul').fadeOut();    
                   $(this).prev().children('ul').fadeOut();
          $(this).next().children('ul').fadeOut();
         $(this).next().children('ul').children('li').children('ul').fadeOut();    

        }); 

       $('li > ul').hide();

     });

    </script>

    But now i am facing problem of prev and next. Suppose in given HTML form if i had expnaded people then if i will expand admission then people is not collapsed so do any have alternative for prev() and next(). Thank you.
```